# How can I update the correct field when the user can type either a username or an email?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm working on an app in rails using react/redux, and I have one text box that can accept either a username or a email. With the help of the post below, I tried the solution of adding another function to handle the email/username input. But it seems that now I'm unable to type the `@` character into the text box (and it seems that the `@` character is getting appended to whatever I type in for the nickname and being set as the user's email). What is the correct way to do this kind of filtering?

Update: I've narrowed the problem down to my `handleLoginInput` function, specifically the first line that is setting the `field` variable; the logic makes sense to me, but for some reason I can't type `@` in the text field, which makes it unable to save the value to the correct field. But when I comment out the `let field=...` and manually put in the `username` field for the `field` variable in the `this.setState...` line below it, it works (for setting the username field); however, when I try doing the same for the `email` field, I'm unable to type in the text box at all.

```
  handleLoginInput(e) {
    let field = e.currentTarget.value.includes('@') ? 'email' : 'username';
    this.setState({ [field]: e.currentTarget.value });
  }
```

// in my form

```
<label>
  <input type="text"
    value={ this.state.username }
    onChange={ e => this.handleLoginInput(e) }
    className="login-input"
    placeholder={ formType === 'Log In' ? "Email address or username" : 
    "Email" }
  />
</label>
```

Comment: do you have submit button ?

Comment: Yes, this snippet is from a form that I'm making (which does have a submit button); just didn't want to paste a bunch of code/make the question harder to read!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `onChange` that way, you need to `setState` first

```
handleLoginValue(e) {
  let field = e.currentTarget.value.includes('@') ? 'email' : 'username'
  this.setState({[field]: e.currentTarget.value});
}


//render
<input type="text"
  value={this.state.username}
  onChange={e => this.handleLoginValue(e)}
  className="login-input"
  placeholder={formType === 'Log In' ? "Email address or username" : "Email"}
/>

<button onClick={this.onSubmit}>
  Submit
<button>
```

Comment: Ah ok, so if I'm understanding this correctly, first I need to save it into the state as the `loginInput`. Then when the user hits the submit button, the `onSubmit` function handles updating the right field?

Comment: Hm, actually, let me post the entire form and my handleSubmit function; I think I did something similar but the email and nickname still aren't getting set to the user's state :(

Comment: I will give it a try! And just making sure, but for the value, did you mean `this.state.loginInput`? Also I just realized that I don't have a `loginInput` field in the initial state; do I need to add that one as well?

Comment: Hmm so I gave it a try and I'm unable to type `@`  in the text box :( I'll add the a snapshot of what my parameters look like when I try to enter an email above!